# Throws an exception on a return while get another table data through foreign key in .NET 5 Web API

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

Doctor detail include into patient object in this method but it return a exception.

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetPatient")]
    public IActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        Patient patient = _dataRepository.Get(id);

        if(patient==null)
        {
            return NotFound("The Patient record couldn't be found");
        }
        patient.Doctor = _doctorep.Get(patient.doctorId);
        return Ok(patient);
    }
```

The exception is

System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.
at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_SerializerCycleDetected(Int32 maxDepth)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ICollectionOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ICollectionOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ICollectionOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ICollectionOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ICollectionOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ICollectionOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ICollectionOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ICollectionOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ICollectionOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ICollectionOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

## HEADERS

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:44330
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Postman-Token: 40ca8a9a-7ef2-4de5-9452-4d18c30ce264

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the patient class includes a field with the doctor class type, and the doctor class includes a patient class field. The result is a cyclic dependence. Because of this, the serializer cannot serialize the patient object to a normal json object. To solve this problem, I would advise using the dto object pattern. For example,

```
public class PatientDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DoctorDto Doctor { get; set; }
}

public class DoctorDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

In this case doctor doesn't include property with class Patient

Comment: These two entities relationship is one-to-many. In this case is it ok?

Comment: Yes it is. But you will need to write a conversion from Patient class to PatientDto class.